# How can I find the sspList id and termSetList id for a TaxonomyWebTaggingControl?

Tags: managed-metadata, office-365, taxonomy, term-store

I'm trying to create a page layout that includes a `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl` on an Office 365 site.  I do not have access to PowerShell.  I have the SspId and TermSetId but cannot figure out how to get the sspList and termSetList IDs.  How might I go about finding those IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Site Settings` -> `Term Store Management` (under `Site Administration`)

To specify [TaxonomyWebTaggingControl.SSPList Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.ssplist%28v=office.14%29.aspx) select the root node that corresponds to `Term Store` and find `Unique identifier` property that displays `TermStoreId` value

To specify [TaxonomyWebTaggingControl.TermSetList Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.termsetlist%28v=office.14%29.aspx) select Term Set node and find `Unique identifier` property that displays `TermSetId` value

[image]